# Execute function only if other is completed, if its not - wait and execute right after completion JS

Tags: javascript

I have two `onclick` functions on page:

```
function fn_name_1() {
  //do buch of stuff
}

function fn_name_2() {
  //do buch of stuff
}
```

When user clicks on `fn_name_1()` it starts executing which is take a while (about 4 seconds to complete).

If user clicks on `fn_name_2()` while `fn_name_1()` is in process it messes `fn_name_1()`.

I had tried to `setTimeOut` for several second for `fn_name_2()` but it an awful user experience because when they hit the button they expect immediate result on their actions.

Basically I want to:

Scenario 1

User hit `fn_name_2()` button, its check if `fn_name_1()` is running and if it is not - proceed with executing `fn_name_2()` as normal.

Scenario 2

User hit `fn_name_2()` button, its check if `fn_name_1()` is running and if it dit, wait for completion **and** start executing automatically right after `fn_name_1()` is completed.

How it can be solved?

Comment: So we need to see which kind of function that you're running that take all this time.

Comment: What exactly is `fn_name_1` doing that takes 4 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have a variable which is accessible to both functions:

```js
let runningTestOne = false;

function testOne(callback) {
  console.log('Starting testOne');
  runningTestOne = true;
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    runningTestOne = false;
    console.log('done with testOne');
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }, 5000);
};

function testTwo() {
  if (runningTestOne) {
    console.log('cannot run');
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('can run test two');
  }
};

function runWithCallback() {
  testOne(testTwo);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testOne()">Test One</button>
<button onclick="testTwo()">Test Two</button>
<button onclick="runWithCallback()">With callback</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make fn_name_1 asynchronous, and let it return a promise, then you can store that promise, and only execute the second task when the promise resolved:

```
 function fn_name_1() {
   //do buch of stuff
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
   });
 }

 let isDone = fn_name_1();

 function fn_name_2() {
   isDone.then(() => {
     //do buch of stuff
   });
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about your suggestion, including "1000" value  (what is for for my case)? @Jonas Wilms

Answer (score -1):

something like this?

```
var wait=false;
function fn_name_1() {
  wait=true;
  //do bunch of stuff
  wait=false;
}

function fn_name_2() {
  while(wait){/*do nothing*/}
  //do bunch of stuff
}
```